# C XV6 avoid Zombie in forks without wait() or pipes

Tags: c, pipe, fork, zombie-process, xv6

I have an Assignment (yes I know everyone loves homework questions), in which I'm supposed to be allowing the CPU scheduler pick which of two forked processes it runs next.  Essentially, I `fork()`, then pass a number to an `exec()` in each fork that simply counts up to that number, printing to screen.  The objective is to show how the Scheduler is Round Robining between each one.  But they keep throwing `Zombie!` a little ways in.

Doing some research, it's because I need to have the parent `wait()` on the child, or at the least use pipes to make sure they don't stumble on each other.  But that defeats the purpose of what I've set out to do, as I am now arbitrarily setting the schedule through `wait()` or pipes.

Does anyone know how to let two forked processes just run next to each other without throwing a `Zombie!`without making them wait on each other?

Comment: How would using `wait` set the schedule?

Comment: Because the parent waits for the child to complete work before running itself, instead of both just sending work to the Scheduler and it deciding who goes next.

Comment: Have the parent fork two children and let them run free.